# actionscript: assembling an new array from many arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

The following function takes user input for the starting and ending lesson of the user's  selected range, then uses a loop to pull each lesson array (from an array of arrays) and then randomly splice it into a new array. The end result for the selection of lessons 3 to 5, for example, would be that the new array (randArray) has all of the data from each lesson in the range randomized, first three, then four, then five. This all works fine, but I can imagine that this is probably not the most efficient way to do this. What is the most compact and efficient way to create a new array from a subset of existing arrays? Since it works well I am content, but would be fascinated to learn better methods and to know why they are better (in addition to being more compact). I chose this method because there was already a lot of code for using just single lessons with one array and this lets me add a range of lessons to that one array without changing any of the other code.

```
function initializeRange():void {
    for (i = startLesson; i < (endLesson + 1); i++) { 
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                duplicate = elementArray[i].slice(0);
                while (duplicate.length > 1 ) {
                    randArray.push(duplicate.splice(Math.ceil(Math.random() *
                    (duplicate.length - 1)), 1)[0]);
                }
                break;
           case 2:
                duplicate = elementArray[i].slice(0);
                while (duplicate.length > 1 ) {
                    randArray.push(duplicate.splice(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 
                    (duplicate.length - 1)), 1)[0]);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                duplicate = elementArray[i].slice(0);
                while (duplicate.length > 1 ) {
                    randArray.push(duplicate.splice(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 
                    (duplicate.length - 1)), 1)[0]);
                }
            break;
            //case "etc.":
            //and so on for the rest of the lessons     
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You need to use `Math.floor()` instead of `Math.ceil()` or else the first element of the array will never get into the resultant array. Otherwise, your method is pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `push.apply`, or `concat`.

They are both doing the same thing - adding elements to specific array, providing subset of another array. Either ways you must select (`splice`) the subset that you need to add.

These two methods are way better, because you don't need to iterate over all items (could be thousands).